# Get null for innerRef of Formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

When I try to get reference on formik, I get null in current field of ref object.

```
const formikRef = useRef();
...

  <Formik
    innerRef={formikRef}
    initialValues={{
      title: '',
    }}
    onSubmit={(values) => console.log('submit')}
  >
```

And next:

```
useEffect(() => {

    console.log(formikRef);
  }, []);
```

Get:

```
Object {
  "current": Object {
    "current": null,
  },
}
```

How can I fix this problem?
Help please.

Comment: you're sure it's supposed to be `innerRef` not just `ref`? and I don't think you're supposed to use both `createRef()` and `useRef()` together.

Comment: I tried only ref and simple useRef() but get or undefined or null

Answer (score 6):

If you want to call submit function outside Formik, you can use *useImperativeHandle*. [Document](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle)

```
// Children Component

const Form = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues,
    validationSchema,
    onSubmit,
    ...rest // other props
  })

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    ...formik
  }))

  return ** Your form here **
})
```

and using:

```
// Parent Component

const Parent = () => {
  const formRef = useRef(null)

  const handleSubmitForm = (values, actions) => { 
    // handle logic submit form
  }

  const onSubmit = () => {
    formRef.current.submitForm()
  }

  return (<>
    <Form ref={formRef} onSubmit={handleSubmitForm} />
    <button type="button" onClick={onSubmit}>Submit</button>
   </>)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the ref only when it has value, and add the dependency in useEffect on the ref.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (formikRef.current) {
        console.log(formikRef);
    }
  }, [formikRef]);
```

Remember, that refs handle it's actual value in .current property.

Comment: Hmmm... I assume that it's the up-to-date Formik spec: https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik . But I canot see, that `<Formik>` element take any `innerRef` prop... Are You sure, that this library is supporting it?

Comment: Find example https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-codesandbox-template-f4o7s but in my case it does not work

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was adding variables inside useEffect's [].
For my case, it was `[ref.current, show]`.

Add an `if(ref.current) {...}` before any `ref.current.setFieldValue` in `useEffect` body as well or `ref.current?.setFieldValue`.

This cost me several hours, I hope you're better off.